# How to send grails <g:link> params as POST

Tags: grails, gsp

In my application when I use

```
 <g:link params=[:] />
```

The params are shown in the URL which I don't want. 
Is there anyway to send the params without showing in the URL as we do by POST method?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[g:link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) is a Tag to create a Link, there is no such thing as a Link with POST params, POST and GET (as others) are [methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_methods) available when you submit data via a form or an ajax request.

Depends on the context you may generate an ajax call or a form for do that.

```
<g:form controller="myController" action="myAction">
  <g:hiddenField name="myField" value="myValue" />
  <g:submitButton name="Submit" value="Submit" class="lnk" />
</gform>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<g:link class="btn btn-success"  id="class.id" onclick='UsingPost();'>SOME LABLE HERE </g:link>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function UsingPost(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{"model":${pleaseUseTheModelyouHaveLoaded}"}, 
        url:'${createLink(action: 'save')}',
        success:function(data,textStatus){
        jQuery('#success').html(data);},
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: be aware, that when using a link to create a HTTP POST request, it could be a little odd to the user, because with a link is (and with it a HTTP GET) associated as a safe and idempotent operation. Due to this, it can be executed more than one time and this leads to the same result (no side effects). On the other Hand, a HTTP POST is per definition not idempotent and not safe, so no one will be the opinion to execute it several times (like your save method mentioned here). So the bottom line of this is, that a GET / POST distinction should not only be done because of the attributes in the url.

Answer (score 0):

`<g:link></g:link>` on processing becomes `<a href=""></a>` so any params passed to the glink will always be available in the url. 
In case you do not want then in the url then you will have to use a form.

Comment: other than using a form, no other options?

Comment: Also you may try to use WebSockets.
And there are many ways to do that without HTTP.

Comment: there are always some ways to do things. but it depends on the use case, if you just need to hit a method with some params, then in that case it won't be a really good option.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use jquery:

```
<g:link id="my_link">This is my link</g:link>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#my_link').click(function() {
        $.post('/url_for_post_request');
    });
</script>
```

There's also [remoteLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html) functionality in Grails but it's deprecated so it's better to avoid using this.

Another option would be to use form. The important fact is that you can define your form somewhere and place submit button anywhere on the website - you just need to use `form` attribute of `g:actionSubmit`:

```
<g:form method="post" action="..." name="form-name">...</g:form>
```

and `g:actionSubmit`:

```
<g:actionSubmit form="form-name" action="..." value="Label"/>
```

Comment: thanks for d reply. in g:actionSubmit action, can we give complete url with parameters?

Comment: You can use `url` attribute of `g:form`. Parameters should be passed as hidden fields in form.

Comment: it should be "elementId" instead of "id" in the g:link.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `<g:link params=[:] />` to an controller/action then in the action do a redirect.

```
<g:link action="formSubmit" params="[id:3]">send</g:link>

class TestController {

    def index() {
    }

    def formSubmit(Long id) {
        // you can use the id param, or add it to flash scope
        redirect action: "index"
    }
}
```

So the id parameter will not be displayed in the resulting url.